# Definite Article Help

Tags: articles, definite-article

Do I need to use the definite article in a Park District name or acronym? IE, this hypothetical with the Chicago Parks Department:

> "The CPD will not compete against organizations currently meeting a program need."

Comment: Yes, you need to use the definite article with many *impersonal* proper nouns, such as the names of government agencies.  Could you add more detail to explain why this is confusing for you?

Comment: @Andrew Are you sure about that? "CHP shut down the 405" sounds fine to me.

Comment: @Tashus  I suppose that works, but only in news articles, and it (in effect) *personifies* the agency.  I also suspect it depends on which style guide the news service follows, as some might be fine with, *"**NYPD** has issued the following statement"* while others would require *"**An NYPD spokesperson** has issued the following statement"*

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is the nearly universal form. But there seem to be a few exceptions. For example I think that we would say "UNESCO encourages international peace," not "The UNESCO," although if we wrote out the abbreviated words we would say "The United Nations..."